# microsoft batch: Read text file into variable and place into another file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, io

I am not very skilled with batch so I am really struggling.

I have two text files and essentially I am trying to insert the contents of one file into the other.
Basically one file describes the geometry of an object and the other is a program that will display that geometry.

My basic methodlogy so far is to read the geomtry file into a variable:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


rem ** The two empty lines are necessary
set "content="

for /f "delims=" %%x in (%replace%) do (
   set "content=!content!%%x"
)

echo(!content!
endlocal
```

And then look through my display program file for a predefined "tag":

```
set "search=noGeometrySpecified"
```

Which will then be replaced with one really long string: `content`

One of the problems I currently have is that `setlocal ... endlocal` define some sort of scope (as I said very uncertain about batch scripts) which doesn't allow `content` to be accessed in my search and replace part of my script. But I can't get it to work with them sharing some sort of scope.

As far as I can tell both separate parts of my script (load entire geometry file, and search and replace in display program file) work, but I can't get them to talk with each other.

Here is my full code:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=noGeometrySpecified"
set "replace=test_geom/\EIN.b18"


setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


rem ** The two empty lines are necessary
set "content="

for /f "delims=" %%x in (%replace%) do (
   set "content=!content!%%x"
)

echo(!content!
endlocal


set "textfile=index.html"
set "newfile=index-active.html"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%content%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
 ))>"%newfile%"

 pause
```

Comment: You can just use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and `endlocal` **once** with the whole batch file as it's scope.

Comment: Does `set "replace=test_geom/\EIN.b18"` specify a file path? Note that the path separator in Windows is `\ `but not `/`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "search=noGeometrySpecified"
set "replace=test_geom/\EIN.b18"
set "content="

for /f "delims=" %%x in (%replace%) do (
   set "content=!content!%%x"
)

echo(!content!

set "textfile=index.html"
set "newfile=index-active.html"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    set "line=!line:%search%=%content%!"
    echo(!line!
 ))>"%newfile%"

 pause
```

Hmm - seems to be a case of sprinkling `setlocal` and `endlocal` at random in hope.

`setlocal` is required to enable `delayedexpansion` (use of `!var!` to extract the run-time value of a variable where `%var%` extracts the parse-time value). It remains in effect until an `endlocal` or end-of-file is reached.

`endlocal` restores the environment and `delayedexpansion` status as it stood when the previous matching `setlocal` was executed. Critically, it backs out any environment changes that were made since that last `setlocal`.

Consequently, the `endlocal` following the `echo(!content!` in the original code backs out the chanes that have just been made to the value of `content` so it reverts to its original value, *nothing*.

Since you want to retain it value for use in the remainder of the code, that `endlocal` must be removed.

Since `delayedexpansion` has already been invoked and is no longer removed by the `endlocal`, it is not necessary to re-invoke it within the `for` loop, so the new `setlocal` and its matching `endlocal` can be removed.

There appears to be no reason to establish the `LF` variable, since it's not used, so I've disposed of that as well.

Personal preference about invoking the `setlocal` on the same line as the `@echo off` or as a separate line. I prefer separate line.

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation, that is immensely helpful. The LF was originally there to add a line break character but left it out while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

As [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947) already explained in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42638401), you placed `setlocal` and `endlocal` wrongly.

Here is an alternative way of rewriting your script -- explanations follow below:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "search=noGeometrySpecified"
set "replace=test_geom/\EIN.b18"

set "content="
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("%replace%") do (
   set "item=%%x"
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   for /F "delims=" %%a in ("content=!content!!item!") do (
       endlocal
       set "%%a"
   )
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo(!content!
endlocal

set "textfile=index.html"
set "newfile=index-active.html"
> "%newfile%" (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%textfile%") do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!line:%search%=%content%!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
pause
```

As you can see, toggling delayed expansion can be used, but you must consider that any variable changes are lost beyond `endlocal` (unless you establish some countermeasures).

1. Let us first concentrate on the second `for /F` loop structure:

   ```cmd
   set "textfile=index.html"
   set "newfile=index-active.html"
   > "%newfile%" (
       for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%textfile%") do (
           set "line=%%i"
           setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
           echo(!line:%search%=%content%!
           endlocal
       )
   )
   ```

   Toggling delayed expansion as you are doing is already fine here. It can avoid loss of exclamation marks; when expanding `%%i` in case delayed expansion is disabled, everything is fine; when expanding `%%i` in case delayed expansion is enabled, exclamation marks get lost (or cause other unexpected results) as such are consumed by the delayed expansion feature; the same is true for normal environment variable expansion line `%var%`.

   After `setlocal`, you do not need to set variable `line`, you could immediately echo the manipulated string; but even if you do reassign `line`, there is no problem because `line` is not used behind `endlocal`, it is newly assigned within the next loop iteration.
2. Now let us focus on the first `for /F` loop structure:

   ```cmd
   set "content="
   for /F "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("%replace%") do (
      set "item=%%x"
      setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
      for /F "delims=" %%a in ("content=!content!!item!") do (
          endlocal
          set "%%a"
      )
   )
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   echo(!content!
   endlocal
   ```

   Again we want to avoid loss of exclamation marks by toggling delayed expansion. However, this is tricky here, because you need to pass variable `content` over to the next loop iteration. So at first `%%x` is assigned to an interim variable `item` while delayed expansion is disabled; then the concatenation is done while delayed expansion is enabled, but the reassignment to variable `content` is delayed to a later point of time after `endlocal`, using a `for /F` loop that is iterating once only and returns the entire assignment expression in `%%a`, which is passed to a `set` command after `endlocal`. Since delayed expansion is disabled after the loop structure has been finished, it needs to be reenabled for echoing `content` again; of course normal expansion like `echo(%content%` could also work, but it might fail in case `content` contains some special characters, so it should be avoided.
3. Finally, the entire script begins with a `setlocal` command with all options explicitly specified and ends with an `endlocal` command, so the batch script does not depend on the settings of the calling `cmd` instance and does not affect its environment.